# Why is my UIPickerView not animating like it should be?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uipickerview

so this is basically like a slot machine type thing, very basic, but the problem Im having is that when you click the spin button the movement of the components is not animated, even though i have sent the animated argument a YES  BOOL. I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Nick

ps download the entire project here: http://files.me.com/knyck2/dcca9y

```
  //
       //  CustomPickerViewController.m
  //  Pickers
  //
  //  Created by Nicholas Iannone on 1/29/10.
  //  Copyright 2010 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
  //

  #import "CustomPickerViewController.h"


  @implementation CustomPickerViewController

  @synthesize column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, picker, winLabel;

  -(IBAction) spin : (id) sender {

 NSLog(@"even got here");

 BOOL win = NO;

 int numInRow = 1;

 int lastVal = -1;

 for (int i = 0; 1 < 5; i++) {
 int newValue = random() % [self.column1 count];

 if (newValue == lastVal) {
    NSLog(@"even got here");

numInRow++;
}
else 
    numInRow = 1;

    lastVal = newValue;
[picker selectRow:newValue inComponent:i animated:YES];
[picker reloadComponent:i];
if (numInRow >= 3) 
    win = YES;

NSLog(@"even got here");

 }

 if (win) 
winLabel.text = @"winner!";

          else {
winLabel.text = @"";
          NSLog(@"even got here");
          }

  }

  /*
   // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller      programmatically                and want to perform customization that is not appropriate      for viewDidLoad.
  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
// Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
  }
  */


  // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from           a nib.
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
 UIImage *seven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"seven.png"];
 UIImage *bar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];
 UIImage *crown = [UIImage imageNamed:@"crown.png"];
 UIImage *cherry = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cherry.png"];
 UIImage *lemon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lemon.png"];
 UIImage *apple = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"];

for (int i = 1; i <= 5 ;  i++) {
    UIImageView *sevenView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: seven];
    UIImageView *barView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: bar];
    UIImageView *crownView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: crown];
    UIImageView *cherryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:      cherry];
    UIImageView *lemonView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: lemon];
    UIImageView *appleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: apple];


    NSArray *imageViewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:      sevenView, barView, crownView, cherryView, lemonView, appleView, nil];
    NSString *fieldName =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",      i];
    [self setValue:imageViewArray forKey:fieldName];
    [fieldName release];
    [imageViewArray release];

    [sevenView release];
    [crownView release];
    [barView release];
    [cherryView release];
    [lemonView release];
    [appleView release];

     }

 srandom(time(NULL));
 [super viewDidLoad];
  }



  /*
  // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
  -     (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
  }
  */

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
  }

  - (void)viewDidUnload {
 [super viewDidUnload];
 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
  }


  - (void)dealloc {
 [picker release];
 [winLabel release];
 [column1 release];
 [column2 release];
 [column3 release];
 [column4 release];
 [column5 release];


 [super dealloc];
  }


  #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods

  -(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *)  pickerView {

 return 5;
  }


  -(NSInteger) pickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:           (NSInteger) component {

 return [self.column1 count];

  }

  #pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods

  -(UIView *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent: (NSInteger) component reusingView : (UIView *)view {

 NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d", component + 1];
 NSArray *array = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
 NSLog(@"got here yo");
 return [array objectAtIndex: row];
 NSLog(@"holyshit");


  }

  @end
```

Comment: sorry the first link to the project was an older version that didn't work, the new link there does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back and compared my code to the book that this project is listed in and I noticed that my code would perform as expected (with animation) if I were to build into a 3.1.2 sdk and iphone sim. So something in the new xcode is skanking the animation, at least that is the way it appears.

Comment: I have the same problem.   Either in iOS4+ or iOS5+, the programmatic animation of the UIPickerView has changed to be very abrupt, not smooth like the smooth deceleration you get when manually flicking the UIPickerView.    Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not animating because you do `[picker reloadComponent:i]` right after selecting a row with animation.  Reloading probably causes any animation to stop, and shouldn't be necessary since you're not actually changing the contents of the picker.

Comment: i got rid of it and still the same, any other ideas? is it maybe something in the nib?